# Problem with many-to-many relationship in EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I have the follwing 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Params](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DisplayName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Params2Items](
    [ParamID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL)
```

and 2 corresponding classes

```
public class Item
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ItemParameter> Params { get; set; }
    }


 public class ItemParameter
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }            
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

To set mapping I use EntityTypeConfiguration class

```
public class ItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Item>
    {
        public ItemConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(i => i.ID);
            Property(i => i.Name).IsRequired();


            HasMany(x => x.Params).WithMany(k => k.Items)
                 .Map(m => m.ToTable("Params2Items").MapLeftKey("ParamID").MapRightKey("ItemID"))
                 ;

            ToTable("Items");
        }
    }
```

When I try to enumerate Params collection I get "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." exception

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (KMCatalog context = new KMCatalog())
            {
                foreach (var s in context.Items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s.Name);

                    foreach (var itemParameter in s.Params) //exception here
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(itemParameter.DisplayName);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
```

I use Ef Code First RC

Answer (score 5):

This is problem called multiple active result sets (also known as MARS). Your first `foreach` has opened `DataReader` reading `Items` but in the same time your inner `foreach` triggers lazy loading of `Params`. This will open second concurrent `DataReader`. To allow multiple concurrent data readers on single connection you must allow it in your connection string:

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```